# Why the Kondo effect is important for STM?

Tags: solid-state-physics, microscopy

The [Kondo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kondo_effect) is observed when approaching 0K. Why would this effect be important for [STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope)?

Comment: The question is very brief and context is not clear. A more precise and clearer question is to be posted.

Comment: As a possible concise answer: Kondo effect is a hallmark of strong correlations between the delocalized electrons (in the STM tip) and the localized ($f$ or $d$) orbitals in the sample. This leads to “anomalous” behaviour of physical observables, like zero-bias conductance. As an example, see [this paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v474/n7351/full/nature10148.html)